# Post text on Facebook on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I have is a 'random quote generator'. As the name suggests, it generates random quotes on button click. In this so called app of mine, I have a button that is supposed to post the 'generated quote'on the facebook wall. The same thing works smoothly in case of my twitter button whilst I am not able to do so in case of facebook.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 //alert("hi");
 $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=40",function(json){
  //alert("hello");
  var colour_arr = ["YellowGreen","Turquoise","Tomato","Teal","SteelBlue","SlateBlue","SeaGreen","SandyBrown","Red","Purple","PaleVioletRed","PaleGreen","Orange","MediumVioletRed","MediumTurquoise","Magenta","LimeGreen","LightSalmon","Khaki","Gold","DodgerBlue","DeepPink","DarkOrange","Crimson","Aquamarine"];
  var colour_num = 0;
  var num = 0;
  var html_quote = "";
  /*json.forEach(function(val){
   html += "<h3 id='quote'>" + val.content + "</h3>";
  });*/
  var html_author = "";
  html_quote = "<h3 id='quote' class='colour'><i class='fa fa-quote-left' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + json[num].content + "</h3>";
  html_author = "<h5 id='author' class='colour'> - " + json[num].title + "</h5>";
  $("#quote-column").html(html_quote);
  $("#author-column").html(html_author);
  $(".colour").css("color",colour_arr[colour_num]);
  $(".bg-colour").css("background-color",colour_arr[colour_num]);
  $("#new-quote-btn").on("click",function(){
   //alert("hello");
   colour_num++;
   num++;
   //alert(num);
   html_quote = "<h3 id='quote' class='colour'><i class='fa fa-quote-left' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + json[num].content + "</h3>";
   html_author = "<h5 id='author' class='colour'> - " + json[num].title + "</h5>";
   $("#quote-column").html(html_quote);
   $("#author-column").html(html_author);
   $(".my-btn").css("color","white");
   $(".colour").css("color",colour_arr[colour_num]);
   $(".bg-colour").css("background-color",colour_arr[colour_num]);
  });
  var randomQuote = json[num].content.replace("<p>","");
  randomQuote = randomQuote.replace("</p>","");
  $("#twitter-btn").on("click",function(){
   //alert(json[num].content);
   //var randomQuote = json[num].content.replace("<p>","");
   //randomQuote = randomQuote.replace("</p>","");
   //alert(randomQuote);
   window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + randomQuote,"_blank");
   //location.href = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + json[num].content;
   //$(this).attr("href","https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + json[num].content);
  });
  $("#fb-btn").on("click",function(){
   window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://codepen.io/iamrkcheers/pen/gRjoeZ","_blank");
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

```css
.box {
 background-color : white;
 border-radius : 5px;
}

.my-btn {
 color : white;
}

#twitter-btn, #fb-btn {
 width : 40px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body class="bg-colour">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="main-row">
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="main-column">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="row" id="row-containing-block">
     <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 box" id="column-containing-block">
      <br>
      <div class="row" id="quote-row">
       <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10" id="quote-column">
        <!-- <h3 id="quote"></h3> -->
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="author-row">
       <div class="col-md-offset-7 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8" id="author-column">
        <!-- <h5 id="author"></h5> -->
       </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row" id="btn-row">
       <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10" id="btn-column">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default my-btn bg-colour" id="twitter-btn"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default my-btn bg-colour" id="fb-btn"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default my-btn bg-colour pull-right" id="new-quote-btn">New Quote</button>
       </div>
      </div>
      <br>
     </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my working example ..

https://codepen.io/iamrkcheers/pen/gRjoeZ

Instead of the "Say something about this .." text, I want my 'random quote'.
Anyway to do this ?!?
Anyhelp is appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method..

```
using Facebook;

private string PostFacebookWall(string accessToken, string message) {
    var responsePost = "";
    try {
        //create the facebook account object
        var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["message"] = message;
        responsePost = objFacebookClient.Post("feed", parameters);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
    }
    return responsePost;
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a response in JavaScript !